# XcodeBuild returns exit status zero even if it failed

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

My Jenkins scripts are running xcodebuild and archive commands. but xcodebuild and archive command don't exit 1 instead it goes to 0 and making  Jenkins build as a success. how they resolve a workaround for these build and archive  steps.

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace "Testworkspace.xcworkspace" -scheme "TestSchema" -archivePath build/SevenNowStore -configuration Release clean archive CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual PROVISIONING_PROFILE=”XXXXXXXQADistribution” CODE_SIGNING_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution: X-XXXX, Inc"
```

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "build/XXXXXXe.xcarchive" -exportPath "build/SXXXXXe" -exportOptionsPlist "ExportOptions_V2.plist"
```

Excepted: xcodebuild command line to exit with 1 in case of error's to mark build as a failure.

Actual: current xcodebuild and xcodearchive command need to exiting with 0 status making it build as a success instead of failure.